# Place and fit n of elements between two existing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

Have two elements with fixed width (in %).

First element positioned `left: 0`, second element positioned `right: 0`;

Need to append some N of elements between these two elements, so each of the new appended elements have same width (depending on available space between main elements).

http://jsfiddle.net/hXUyh/1/

The problem is that new elements are positioned NOT accurately (crossing each other or leaving some extra space between) and NOT consistently with different browser's window sizes.

Please help.

I understand that different browsers will give different output, but this script will be limited to Google Chrome use only.

Comment: haven't added `$(window).resize()`, so you need to Run script everytime browser's window size is changed to see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        $('<div/>').appendTo('body')
    }
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var firstWidth = $('#element-0').width();
        var r = ($(window).width() - (firstWidth * 2) - 2) / 9;
        $('div').slice(2, 11).each(function(i) {
            $(this).css({
                left: i == 0 ? firstWidth : firstWidth + r * (i),
                width: r
            })
        })
    }).resize() 
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yav9Q/

Comment: This works. But borders are still crossing for first and last elements. http://jsfiddle.net/yav9Q/2/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirements not too long ago. Without questioning or changing your strategy/code, here is a fiddle showing as close as I can get it:
http://jsfiddle.net/hXUyh/3/
(Note that I haven't catered for resizing as your original code didn't)

The issue that the width() jquery function will round. So your maths will always be a little bit off. I've improved this by using calculations on window.innerWidth, it will be a little bit misaligned because of the floating point widths. Using floating point widths for pixel perfect alignment is not the way to go.

If you want perfect alignment, use padding. Here is an example using the smallest padding possible: http://jsfiddle.net/hXUyh/8/
The maths is much easier if you don't need a border.

Comment: Thanks, but in your code elements are also placed inconsistently. http://jsfiddle.net/hXUyh/4/. See element-1 and 9 are shifted.

Comment: The elements are placed inconsistently because you're using floating point pixels. I updated my answer to include an example of a pixel perfect layout that uses padding: http://jsfiddle.net/hXUyh/8/

Comment: Now I'm dependent on border width? http://jsfiddle.net/hXUyh/9/. Nevermind, I will post my unique solution later.

Comment: yes, because the maths will be different. sorry just realised you wanted non-overlapping: http://jsfiddle.net/hXUyh/10

Comment: not consistent still. spaces between boxes is different from left to right.